# Configure argparse to accept quoted arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I am writing a program which, among other things, allows the user to specify through an argument a module to load (and then use to perform actions). I am trying to set up a way to easily pass arguments through to this inner module, and I was attempting to use ArgParse's `action='append'` to have it build a list of arguments that I would then pass through.

Here is a basic layout of the arguments that I am using

```
parser.add_argument('-M', '--module',
                    help="Module to run on changed files - should be in format MODULE:CLASS\n\
                          Specified class must have function with the signature run(src, dest)\
                          and return 0 upon success",
                    required=True)
parser.add_argument('-A', '--module_args',
                    help="Arg to be passed through to the specified module",
                    action='append',
                    default=[])
```

However - if I then try to run this program with `python my_program -M module:class -A "-f filename"` (where I would like to pass through the `-f filename` to my module) it seems to be parsing the `-f` as its own argument (and I get the error `my_program: error: argument -A/--module_args: expected one argument`

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the `sys.argv`.  Do the quotes make it through to the parser or are they swallowed by the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-M', '--module',
                    help="Module to run on changed files - should be in format MODULE:CLASS\n\
                          Specified class must have function with the signature run(src, dest)\
                          and return 0 upon success",
                    )
parser.add_argument('-A', '--module_args',
                    help="Arg to be passed through to the specified module",
                    action='append',
                    default=[])
import sys
print(sys.argv)
print(parser.parse_args())
```

I get:

```
1028:~/mypy$ python stack45146728.py -M module:class -A "-f filename"
['stack45146728.py', '-M', 'module:class', '-A', '-f filename']
Namespace(module='module:class', module_args=['-f filename'])
```

This is using a linux shell.  The quoted string remains one string, as seen in the `sys.argv`, and is properly interpreted as an argument to `-A`.

Without the quotes the `-f` is separate and interpreted as a flag.

```
1028:~/mypy$ python stack45146728.py -M module:class -A -f filename
['stack45146728.py', '-M', 'module:class', '-A', '-f', 'filename']
usage: stack45146728.py [-h] [-M MODULE] [-A MODULE_ARGS]
stack45146728.py: error: argument -A/--module_args: expected one argument
```

Are you using `windows` or some other OS/shell that doesn't handle quotes the same way?

---

In [Argparse `append` not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150153/argparse-append-not-working-as-expected)

you asked about a slightly different command line:

```
1032:~/mypy$ python stack45146728.py  -A "-k filepath" -A "-t"
['stack45146728.py', '-A', '-k filepath', '-A', '-t']
usage: stack45146728.py [-h] [-M MODULE] [-A MODULE_ARGS]
stack45146728.py: error: argument -A/--module_args: expected one argument
```

As I already noted `-k filepath` is passed through as one string.  Because of the space, `argparse` does not interpret that as a flag.  But it does interpret the bare '-t' as a flag.

There was a bug/issue about the possibility of interpreting undefined '-xxx' strings as arguments instead of flags.  I'd have to look that up to see whether anything made it into to production.

Details of how strings are categorized as flag or argument can be found in `argparse.ArgumentParser._parse_optional` method.  It contains a comment:

> ```
>     # if it contains a space, it was meant to be a positional
>     if ' ' in arg_string:
>         return None
> ```

http://bugs.python.org/issue9334 `argparse does not accept options taking arguments beginning with dash (regression from optparse)` is an old and long bug/issue on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the (cross question) answer! It seems just padding these quoted args with a space and attempting to instruct my users about this workaround will have to do for now

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to accept arbitrary arguments - there's an example in argparse's doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> argparse.REMAINDER. All the remaining command-line arguments are gathered into a list. This is commonly useful for command line utilities that dispatch to other command line utilities:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo')
>>> parser.add_argument('command')
>>> parser.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
>>> print(parser.parse_args('--foo B cmd --arg1 XX ZZ'.split()))
Namespace(args=['--arg1', 'XX', 'ZZ'], command='cmd', foo='B')
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution - however I believe it would be better (at least for my application) not to accept arbitrary command arguments. At least with the workaround of padding with a space the users still have to intentionally use the `-A` argument